# C# Start Thread inside itself

Tags: c#, multithreading

I try to start a running thread inside itself. Maybe that sounds strange, but that is only to know if it is possible or not.

My call function starts a thread, which includes my function. After that my function makes a query if a specific device has been plugged in previously. If this is true everything is okay and a connection will be done to this device.
If the device is not plugged in at the start of the software, the function makes a query if the device is now plugged in. If this is true it calls it self but if it is false it stops.

Here is the code, which should work for that

```
public void CallFunction()
{
  Thread CheckDevice = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myFunction));
  CheckDevice.Start();
}
private void myFunction()
{
  if (ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn)
  {
    try
    {
      Device.Connect();
    }catch
    {
      //ErrorMessage
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn = SearchDevice())
    {
      Thread.CurrentThread.Start();
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      //InfoMessage
    }
  }
}
```

Would that be possible, that I call the thread like that or is it better to only call the function.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense at all. The code in the ThreadStart delegate will not be executed before the Thread is started. And as said before, you should not explicitly be using Threads at all. Instead, focus on modern approaches like Tasks.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.Start();` seems meaningless. If the current thread isn't running, how can it execute this statement?

Comment: Looks like you're simply trying to call the function from itself. No need to make additional threads, just call the function directly.

Comment: You don't need to do this. Just put a while loop inside your `myFunction`.

Comment: What's wrong with a perfectly good `for`/`while` loop?

Comment: _"Would that be possible, that I call the thread like that"_ - if you actually ran your code you would have found that your code thows a [`ThreadStateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Thread_Start)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its (apart from the ThreadStateException mentioned above) _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: That last answer was correctly that, what I asked. It was only to know, if it is possible. I do not use a while loop because the function only can run 2 times, but thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

just change your myFunction to something like:

```
private void myFunction()
{
  bool connected = false;
  while (!connected)
  {
    if (ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn)
    {
      try
      {
        Device.Connect();
        connected = true;
      } catch
      {
        //ErrorMessage
      }
    }
    else
    {
      ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn = SearchDevice())
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation: You can not start a thread that is already running.

Just do a while loop until you are connected. As it's running in it's own thread it's not affecting the rest of your program.

Comment: when using such loops it is adviseable to have some sort of timeout. So that the while loop does not run for ever in a worst case scenario. The last exit strategy so to say

Comment: That's why these sorts of questions aren't productive on SO.  It turns into a community _code review_ (which is off-topic for SO) for both the question and answer(s)

Comment: Yes, you are right. One could also think about a Thread.Sleep in the loop to not stress the CPU too much.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to invoke an additional thread. I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
private void myFunction()
{
  if (!ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn)
  {
    ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn = SearchDevice()
  }
  if (ConnectionCheck.DevicePluggedIn) {
    try
    {
      Device.Connect();
    }catch
    {
      //ErrorMessage
    }
  }
  else
  {
      //InfoMessage
  }
}
```